Modeling longitidunal relationships without estimating indirect effects
I'm analyzing a three-time point study using structural equation modeling (SEM). I only care about the direct effects of my variables. Is it okay to only model those direct paths, or should I include indirect paths even though I'm not interested in them? Like in the picture below, i want to model it like that. Is this logical to you? Thank you.


Welcome to Cross Validated! Have you thought about a latent growth model?

Thank you, Rick. I have, but Y variable is a time 3 variable that measured only once as a outcome. X, T and Z has only two measurement points but i want to use their respective time points to come up with causal links.

Right, then I see no reason not to model things the way you have it, and I agree with the answer below

It is OK in principle but if you omit paths that are statistically different from zero (e.g., the direct paths from X to Z and/or Y), then the model may show a bad fit and result in biased estimates of the remaining paths that you do include.

Thank you, Christian. Model has a good fit but with the other paths estimated i get non-significant direct paths which i wanted to focus on. It seems like omitting those paths cause significant direct effects.

With "good fit", do you mean a non-significant chi-square test of model fit? It is expected that some or all of the paths in your reduced/simplified model become stronger when you omit the other ones but the question is whether the remaining paths are inflated due to deletion of the other paths.

I meant for other fit indexes such as RMSEA, CFI, SRMR etc. Thank you for the clarification, Christian. I thought something was off with the statistical procedure I wanted to employ.
